# PlotLegends disappearing with list of functions

Tags: plotting, functions, bugs, legending

**Bug introduced in 11.0.0. Fixed in 11.1.0.**

---

Why is it that:

```
Plot[{x^2}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> {"a"}]
```

does fine, but:

```
funcs={x^2};
Plot[funcs, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> {"a"}]
```

makes the legend disappear?

Please note that clearly this is a toy example, so a workaround is not the issue here.  I would like to understand what is going on.  Is it related to what `Plot[]` looks for in its first argument?  I *know* that `funcs==={x^2}`, so that is a list of functions of `x`, which it should be.

Thanx.

Comment: It might be side effect due to the `HoldAll` property of `Plot`. Try `Plot[Evaluate@funcs, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> {"a"}]`

Comment: I can't reproduce your result. If I run your code, the legend is drawn as expected. Which version of Mathematica do you use?

Comment: @Felix in version 11.0.1 the legend do indeed disappear. But adding `Evaluate` they show up.

Comment: @Nasser -- thanx, that worked.  I forgot about that `HoldAll`.

Comment: That's remarkable, considering that they don't disappear in 11.0.0. I have updated to 11.0.1 and can confirm that they now do disappear.

Comment: Why do you put your function within curly brackets (list)?

Comment: @Felix, thank you for checking. Given the change from 11.0.0 to 11.0.1, should I report this to WR (as a bug)?

Comment: @david-g-stork, this is only a toy example. In fact, I have a list of functions of `x`.

Comment: Yes, reporting it makes sense. From a user perspective, it is not clear why the PlotLegends should be related to using or not using Evaluate on the function to be plotted.

Comment: It's a bug. It's fixed in the upcoming release, and I'll update this once that's out the door.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the upcoming release, this works fine.

[image]