# PlotLegends is not working or may be I don't know how to use it

Tags: legending

I am not able to use Plot legend properly. In my case I do have many colors but I don't know how to use Plot Legend judiciously. Any help will be highly appreciable.
Example:

```
Msize:= 5;
a:= 1;
ω := π;
HB[j1_, k_] := -j1 Cos[k*a]; 
HFTB[j1_, k_] := 
      ArrayFlatten@
       Table[HB[j1, k] KroneckerDelta[m + 1, p] + 
         HB[j1, k] KroneckerDelta[m - 1, p] + (m)*ω*
          KroneckerDelta[m, p], {m, -Msize, Msize}, {p, -Msize, Msize}];

eigenergy[j1_, k_] := Module[{EV}, EV = Eigenvalues[HFTB[j1, k]];
  Plot[EV, {k, -π/a, π/a}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]]
Manipulate[eigenergy[j1, k], {j1, 0, 4}]
```

This is output without any PlotLegend *which shows the corresponding values of the lines or curves*.
How to go about it?

[image]

Addendum:
Mathematica 11.0.1 Student edition
Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Do you have the definition of `HB[j1, k]`?

Comment: I think using `Plot[Evaluate[EV],...]` will make the `PlotLegends` option work, although the outcome most probably is not yet very useful...

Comment: Fix the code first. @Diogo already pointed to some missing symbols.

Comment: @Diogo Thank you, I have edited the question.

Comment: Which version of Mathematica are you using? Here on v 10.3 the legends are working fine.

Comment: @Diogo See the edited question.

Comment: I also get expected results with legends (Mathematica 10.2). Could you be more specific about question. This is temporary [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/01qanj6vivp5xkt/file.jpg?dl=0) to the plot and will be deleted in 7 days.

Comment: @ercegovac But still I am not getting the legend. Is it problem with Mathematica 11.0.1. or am I missing something in my code. My result is still the same.

Comment: @L.K. Is the resulting figure that i provided on the link above the expected one? If so, could you upload similar link with printscreen of your notebook. Since two of us got result as expected, the code should not be the problem.

Comment: @ercegovac Yes this what I want.

Comment: @ercegovac Just to support my arguement [Plot](http://imgur.com/a/81Ubz). Am I missing something?

Comment: Seams you are using Mac or Linux. Perhaps it is something implementation specific.I'm using version on windows and as you saw, its working well. Perhaps some of more experienced users, or somebody else with Mac might try. Update your question to make it clear that you are using Mac.

Comment: Perhaps you can check something along [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21792/34848) line? It might be well some problem with manipulate on Ubuntu.

Comment: @ercegovac I think problem is bit different but thanks anyway.

Comment: Albert's suggestion in the second comment is what you need.  I can verify the others' observation that you get the legends with version 10.3 but not with 11.01.  Not sure if it's a bug though, I feel like you **should** have to use `Evaluate` in this situation.  I would even do something like this `vals[j1_, k_] = Eigenvalues[HFTB[j1, k]];
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[vals[j1, k]], {k, -\[Pi]/a, \[Pi]/a}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic],
 {j1, 0, 4}, ContinuousAction -> False]`

Comment: @JasonB. Thanks for your working code. But in 11.01, it is showing merely numbers for legend but that is one, another the update of result after releasing j1 slider is very slow now. Mathematica 11.0.1 is having some problem I suppose.

Comment: @L.K. - I get the [exact same thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJjn2.png) with versions 9.0, 10.3, and 11.0.1: slow manipulate and the legend has only numbers.  I don't see the spot in your code where you specify what value the legends should show.

Comment: @JasonB. Thanks a lot for this. Ya you are right(I have edited my question) but indeed I wanted the values as mentioned in one of the previous comments. Your code did work wonderful, I did tell you that, thanks for above one.

Comment: @L.K. this is a bug and it is essentially identical to [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/135570/52).

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks for this. Indeed the case with new Mathematica